# Trying to identify an Ontario bird photographed in Spring in the Don Valley

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

[image][image: Mystery Bird]

Any help is appreciated! I think this may be a juvenile bird? I thought it might be a brown-headed cowbird, but the plumage and head markings don't seem quite right (compared to examples on the internet)? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.!

Rob aka orbitrob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the location, timing and picture, this bird is a female **Red-winged Blackbird** (*Agelaius phoeniceus*)

In the spring in Ontario, it would be unlikely to have juveniles around, as breeding has just begun unless this photo was taken near the end of Spring. Male Red-winged Blackbirds would be in their dark black plumage with the yellow/red wing patch. Here is a photo of a pair with the male on the left and female on the right.

[image]

You can find more information about them [here](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Red-winged_Blackbird/id)

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank-you! Makes sense as there were a lot of the 'showier' males around. :)